# Add specific file extensions and ignore case

Tags: git, case-sensitive

When I run `git add *.jpg` git will not add files that end with `.JPG` or `.Jpg`. How can we have git ignore case on an add without reconfiguring git? The following would be perfect.

```
git add --ignore-case *.txt
```

The following glob pattern just seems clunky.

```
git add '*.[tT][xX][tT]'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a more general way to have file globbing be case insensive? Then it can be used with *any* program that takes files on the command line.

Comment: So ask for *that* as a bash question, if it's not already in the docs.  I don't recall if regular fileglobs have an extension syntax like Perl RE or the glob replacements used on Windows.